# What is Fish equivalent for <<EOF in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, fish

What is the Fish equivalent for << in Bash, as in

```
$ nc localhost 8888 << EOF
> foo
> EOF
```

In Fish, it crashes

```
> nc localhost 8888 << EOF
fish: Expected redirection specification, got token of type 'Redirect input to file'
nc localhost 8888 << EOF
               ^
```

Comment: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/540

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to the link provided by Etan I found out that such feature is not implemented, and the closest thing available is

```
> echo "\
  foo
  " | nc localhost 8888
```

Answer (score 8):

That is not implemented in Fish.  You can read about Bash/Fish syntax crossovers [HERE](http://hyperpolyglot.org/unix-shells#redirection).