# How to use EOF with curl in Fish Shell?

Tags: shell, curl, fish

How do I use EOF/HEREDOC with curl in Fish shell. Per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357270/what-is-fish-equivalent-for-eof-in-bash), it isn't possible and the suggestion is to use pipes to STDOUT, but the application has to support that and specifically be looking for STDIN. The upstream Fish [issue #530](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/540) is locked for followup. How would I convert this common example in Fish?

```
curl \
--request POST "https://wwww.example.com/api/v1/test/delete" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data @- << EOF
{}
EOF
```

Comment: "but the application has to support that and specifically be looking for STDIN" - HEREDOCS are also sent via stdin! If you can use HEREDOCS you can use other kinds of piping from stdin.

Comment: The semantics of heredocs are: 1. read/interpret the string, 2. write it to a temporary file, 3. start the process with that file as stdin. So there is no real magic happening here, it's all just stdin again! Doing `echo foo > /tmp/somefile; proc < /tmp/somefile; rm /tmp/somefile` is basically what happens, so you can skip the tempfile by just doing `echo foo | proc`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Fish equivalent for <<EOF in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357270/what-is-fish-equivalent-for-eof-in-bash)

Comment: I.e. yes, it is a duplicate because you can simply use pipes. The idea that you can't is simply a misunderstanding.

Comment: I struggled with the duplicated question and answer for a while and it did not answer my question. And the answer doesn't actually work for `curl` specifically. So this question is specifically around how to use `curl` with STDIN `@-` as a workaround for Fish not supporting HEREDOC/EOF.

Comment: But HEREDOCs also only work with `@-`? So the replacement of heredocs with a normal pipe is the exact same thing as in the previous answer, and getting curl to read the header from stdin is the same with both.

Comment: It is exactly the same, but some people like myself see an example e.g. https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/synthetics/#delete-tests

And we say, hrm, how can I use this in fish? Then we go searching and see that Fish doesn't support EOF, then don't actually understand just yet (we are still learning) that it is the same thing and are looking for how to do it the Fish way. And we search and we don't find our answer, and then we eventually figure it out because we found this Q/A, not the other one.

Comment: fwiw, I read the other Q/A and the upstream issue and spent a good 30-60 minutes without getting it and was going to post this simple example on the upstream issue but it was locked. So I figured that I would put it somewhere on the internet and it didn't make sense to post my curl example on the other question. Do you think I should post my curl example as an answer to the other question? I can, I just didn't think it made sense there. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, that would be preferable - "here's an example where you need to enable reading from stdin, which you would also need to do for heredocs" or something?

Comment: I have expanded the section on heredocs in fish's [For Bash Users](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/doc_src/fish_for_bash_users.rst#heredocs) document (link is a preview, the actual render will come out nicer). That should hopefully clarify how this fits together better, and what fish's issue with heredocs is.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe your output to STDOUT and use `@-`:

> Using @- will make curl read the header file from stdin.
> source: `man curl`

```
echo " \
{}
" | \
curl \
--request POST "https://wwww.example.com/api/v1/test/delete" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data @-
```

This isn't as clean as EOF but it does work.